# How to hide back button on a home screen after splash screen in android?

Tags: android

In my app, I have back button as default on toolbar after the splash screen.(i.e) on home page. I don't need any icon or title on my home page toolbar alone.

How can I hide the button on home screen?

If I disable back button on MainActivity by

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

It shows NullPointerException

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        showFragment(homeFragment, Constants.HOME_FRAGMENT, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            showAlertDialog(Constants.EXIT_APP, Constants.APP_NAME);
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
    public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String back_stack_name, boolean isAddToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        if (isAddToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(back_stack_name);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int vid = item.getItemId();
        switch (vid) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it means,  getSupportActionBar() method returns fall.

Comment: S. Then what should I do now to hide default icon in home page alone

Comment: are using actionbaractivity,activity or appcompactactivity?

Comment: Im using appcompact activity

Comment: can you post the exception log in your question.

Comment: No error in log, But while typing in code, it has yellow highlighting on this code. And there is no effect. Still I have back button

Comment: post your activity code.

Comment: What about trying this : `if(getSupportActionBar != null){getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my question.

- In fragments:

**For title without back arrow**

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

**For Title with back arrow**

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

---

- In activity:

**For title without back arrow**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

**For Title with back arrow**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false); getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

---

For colored back button, modify in style

```
<style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>  <!-- white arrow -->
</style>
```

Use theme in toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason:

1) you dont have the support actionbar.

2) you might be hide the supportActionBar using styles.

3) you are hiding it programatically in your activity.

solution:

If you are using toolbar in activty , try using this below code in your onCreate() method:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```